# How to know what control and event raised

Tags: vb.net, events, click, mouse, handle

I have a sub like this:

```
Private Sub mysub (parameters) handles control1.mousemove, control1.mousedown, control2.mousemove, control2.mousedown
 'Statements
End Sub
```

I know what control activate sub but I want to know what event activated the sub (for example control2 activate sub but I want to know the event mousemove or mousedown)

Thanks

Comment: The individual events could call mySub with a parameter indicating the event.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly tell why your event handler was called. The best you're going to be able to do is a scenario like this:

```
Private Sub MouseMove_Handler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles control1.mousemove, control2.mousemove
  MouseCommonCode(sender, e, "MouseMove")
End Sub

Private Sub MouseDown_Handler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles control1.mousedown, control2.mousedown
  MouseCommonCode(sender, e, "MouseDown")
End Sub

Private Sub MouseCommonCode(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs, caller As String)
  'Common Statements
End Sub
```

Though, I would say that this is a pretty odd request, and it would seem like there's *probably* a better way to do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am c# kind of guy, so I am going on a limb here..
Can't you do something like:

```
Private Sub mysub1 (parameters) handles control1.mousemove
  'Statements ...
End Sub

Private Sub mysub2 ( parameters) handles control1.mousedown
  'Statements ...
End Sub
```

And so on?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it.